# Error when setting an input in ReactJS, label is over / overwrites the value of the input set, using the material.ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Good afternoon devs !!

I have a little problem, I'm using reactJS, and I'm using `react-form-hook`, in which I use an `TextField` from Material-UI. When I fill an input with name cep, it calls a function that sends the content from this to an api, which returns, content to fill the input there, The problem happens that when I try to set my inputs with the returned content. The Input label remains on the field, as in the case shown in the photo, in the last input. That came the answer.

the fields first with the setValues ​​of the react-form-hook, but the error persisted after I tried to set this way document.querySelector ('# inputStreet'). value = street;

Finally the way I decided was to create in this inputs that receive update a useState for each

```
const [srua, setSrua] = useState ('');
const [sbairros, setSbairros] = useState ('');
const [scity, setScidade] = useState ('');
const [sUF, setSUF] = useState ('');
```

Only in this way was he able to solve the problem of the label not being on the content of the input, as already exemplified in the photo in the last input, I believe this is not the most correct way, so I would like a help on how to solve this in a more efficient. just like that

[Repository link](https://github.com/JoezerSmaniotto/IvetFront/blob/master/src/Pages/SignIn/index.js).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your `TextField` is that the `InputLabel` does not *shrink*. the label shrinks when the `TextField` is in focus or when the value of the `TextField` is not empty.

But since you are setting the value programmatically, the input is not focused, the value is also not registered because it's *uncontrolled* which means the `TextField` keeps track and updates the `value` internally for you and ignore external `value` if provided.

In order to make the `TextField` controllable, as suggested from the name, you must take control of the `TextField`'s `value` from the beginning which is what you did in the question.

You can also simplify this process by using `react-hook-form`'s [`Controller`](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller). It's a wrapper component to help you pass common props to the *controlled* components

```js
<Controller
  render={({ onChange, onBlur, value, name }) => (
    <TextField
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
      name={name}
      label="Email"
    />
  )}
  name="email"
  control={control}
  // need to initialize value to register the TextField as controlled
  // if we don't provide, the default value is undefined, which means uncontrolled
  defaultValue=""
/>
```

Which can be shortened to this

```js
<Controller
  render={(props) => <TextField {...props} label="Email" />}
  name="email"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63973773/error-when-setting-an-input-in-reactjs-label-is-over-overwrites-the-value-of]